# How to organize a framework is ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader, es6-modules

Is there a "es6 way" to package up a collection of functions into a framework?
Which of the following methods (or alternatives if I've missed something) will work?
I'm using Babel to transpile the code and want to make sure the route I choose is as future proof as possible.

**The background:**

I started a project and would like to pull out a lot of the functionality into it's own framework.
The number of utility functions has gotten large enough that they should be separate from the rest of the app that consumes them.
The classes and functions are organized by folder and each in it's own file like so:

```
app
├─ array
│   ├─ ...
│   ├─ shuffle.js
│   ├─ ...
├─ math
│   ├─ ...
│   ├─ random.js
│   ├─ ...
├─ models
│   ├─ ...
│   ├─ answers.js
│   ├─ model.js
│   ├─ ...
```

So currently in `answers.js` I have includes like:

```
import { shuffle } from './array/shuffle';
import { Random } from './math/random';
import { Model } from './models/model';

class Answers extends Model {
  ...
}
```

Next I'd like to organize and package up a new `myframework` project that I can import from?

```
myframework
├─ model.js
├─ array
│   ├─ ...
│   ├─ shuffle.js
│   ├─ ...
└─ math
    ├─ ...
    └─ random.js
```

**Option 1:**

Build one `myframework.js` file and, what?, namespace the sub-sections?  Then `answers` would look like:

```
import { array.shuffle as shuffle } from 'myframework';
import { math.Random as Random } from 'myframework';
import { Model } from 'myframwork';
```

Or is there a way to declare the sub-sections such that import could look like the following and `myframework.js` is still one file:

```
import { shuffle } from 'myframework/array';
import { Random } from 'myframework/random';
import { Model } from 'myframwork';
```

**Option 2:**

Build one file for each section.  I guess calling the base level `core` or something:

```
myframework
├─ core.js
├─ array.js
└─ math.js
```

And:

```
import { shuffle } from 'myframework/array';
import { Random } from 'myframework/random';
import { Model } from 'myframwork/core';
```

Comment: Does `shuffle.js` only export one single function? Then it should use a default export, not a named one.

Comment: Option 2 seems a lot cleaner, especially when considering that you cannot use namespaces in import/export identifiers

Comment: @bergi It needs to be named because eventually it will be part of the `array.js` module with many exports.

Comment: That only means it needs to be a named export of `array.js`, nothing else. You can also do `export { default as shuffle } from './shuffle.js';`

Comment: Sure that makes sense, but what if the `array` folder in `src` has twenty files each exporting a function?  Then I would need to configure the build system to convert all `export defaults` to named exports when it concats all the files into `array.js`.

Comment: Wait, your build system is just file concatenation? Use something more sophisticated like rollup.js, it'll do that automatically.